# Do Webassembly instances run an entry point function?

Tags: webassembly, entry-point

I am asking a very technical question, when you instantiate a web assembly module, in javascript, does any of the webassembly functions actually get executed before you recieve the instance, or is the webassembly code purely a library, in that after instantiating it you must run any of the exports manually, and no exports or functions in the webassembly, such as a starting point, are implicitly run?

If webassembly ever gets added to the html directly, in future versions, what would the entrypoint of the webassembly module be?

Answer (score 0):

Webassembly instances have a `(start)` section that expresses the entry-point of the webassembly module if there is one.